# Redirect user after verifying that he is connected with Symfony 4 and FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, middleware, fosuserbundle

**Hello world !**
I am a laravel developer but for a while I have been working on symfony projects.
And in my work I have just been faced with a major problem that is running a piece of code after checking whether a user is logged in or not.
On laravel I could use providers, middleware or the basic controller to do it. But there on Symfony 4 I am blocked.
I use the method `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');`
I want every time we check that we can run this method:

```
if ($this->getUser()->getMetaValue('level') == "ADMIN") {
     $ip = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
     $record = $this->get('geoip2.reader')->city($ ip);
     $isoCode = $record->country->isoCode;
     if ($isoCode! = "USA") {
         return $this->render('backOffice/vpn_error.html.twig');
     }
}
```

So every time an administrator is connected we check if it is connected from the United States otherwise it is asked to use a VPN to have an IP address.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: This might be a starting point: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yoshi Thank you !
I have found the solution but I know that it's not the best but for the moment it's satisfied me. I have edit the denyAccessUnlessGranted() method and I force the displaying of error with **echo**
My solution it's like :

```
    /**
     * Throws an exception unless the attributes are granted against the current authentication token and optionally
     * supplied subject.
     *
     * @throws AccessDeniedException
     *
     * @final
     */
    protected function denyAccessUnlessGranted($attributes, $subject = null, string $message = 'Access Denied.')
    {
        if (!$this->isGranted($attributes, $subject)) {
            $exception = $this->createAccessDeniedException($message);
            $exception->setAttributes($attributes);
            $exception->setSubject($subject);

            throw $exception;
        } 
        if ($this->getUser()->getMetaValue('level') == "ADMIN") {
            $ip = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
            $record = $this->get('geoip2.reader')->city($ ip);
            $isoCode = $record->country->isoCode;
            if ($isoCode!= "USA") {
                echo $this->renderView('backOffice/vpn_error.html.twig');
                die();
            } 
        }
    }
```